# How can i Loop in a Json Object Key within Php Values

Tags: php, jquery, json, loops, key

I'm trying to loop inside a json Object key within php values.

I have some Php values which should loop through the function key that always make a new 'items' entry.

The Key Item is showing fields in the front-end and 'items' value should loop the fields with the values from my php values which i get from a wordpress Post Type loop.

````
 $(function(){
        $("#elastic_grid_demo").elastic_grid({
            'showAllText' : 'All',
            'filterEffect': 'popup', // moveup, scaleup, fallperspective, fly, flip, helix , popup
            'hoverDirection': false,
            'hoverDelay': 0,
            'hoverInverse': false,
            'expandingSpeed': 500,
            'expandingHeight': 2200,
            'items' :
            [ ** here should start the loop **
                {
                    'title'         : '<?php echo $titel; ?> <br> <?php echo $name; ?>  ',
                    'description'   : '<?php echo json_encode($vita); ?>',
                    'thumbnail'     : ['<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>'],
                    'large'         : ['<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>', '<?php echo $portrait; ?>'],
                    'img_title'     : ['test ', 'jquery elastic grid 2', 'jquery elastic grid 3', 'jquery elastic grid 4', 'jquery elastic grid 5'],
                    'button_list'   :
                    [
                        { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/', 'new_window' : true },
                        { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/', 'new_window' : false},
                        { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/', 'new_window' : false}
                    ],
                    'tags'          : ['<?php echo $fachgebiet[0];?>']
                }, 
```
````

Comment: I'm sorry, but we have no idea what all those PHP variables come from, what they contain, what you want to loop or what the expected result should be. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Include your attempt and result as well.

Comment: hey @MagnusEriksson. sorry for the bad description. this function makes a filterable grid in the front-end and i have to put my Values from my wordpress custom Post type into this 'item' Key so they are showing up in a loop in the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are doing, are you generating Javscript/Jquery code from PHP?
If yes, here is how you can do it.

I suppose your PHP data is structured similar like this:

```
$data = [
    [
        'title' => 'Dr. med.',
        'name' => 'Fritz Müller',
        ...
    ],
    ....
];
```

Then you can do

```
...
'expandingHeight' : 2200,
'items' : [
<?php 
foreach ($data as $set) {
?>
    {
        'title': '<?=$set['title'];?>',
        ...
    }
<?php
}
?>
],
...
```

...but for readability reasons I recommend to generate your items array before, and then inject it later like so:

```
...
'expandingHeight' : 2200,
'items' : [
    <?=$items?>
],
...
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad description... but this is exactly what i need. Thank you so much. I'm new at stackoverflow =)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, glad I could help!